# Using queues to handle asynchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, design-patterns

The application I'm working on has to fire off multiple requests to an external API. It will receive the results of those requests asynchronously, but then I need to handle each response in a synchronous way. My research tells me there are multiple ways of doing this, but I am considering this idea and wondering if it will work:

Every time I make a call to the external API, its response is entered into the queue as soon as it asynchronously comes back:

```
function genericFetchFunction(url, callback) {
    makeAsyncRequest(url, (result) => {
        addToHandlingQueue({
            data: result,
            callback
        });
    });
}
```

The queue handler pushes the response onto the queue, and initiates the queue firing process.

```
const responseQueue = [];

function addToHandlingQueue(response) {
    responseQueue.push(response);
    if (responseQueue.length == 1) {
        fireQueue();
    }
}

function fireQueue() {
    let item = responseQueue.shift();
    item.callback(item.data);
    if (responseQueue.length > 0) {
        fireQueue();
    }
}
```

Would this code work how I expect? Will all results get into the queue and their callbacks fired in sequence? If not - why not?

EDIT: The use case for this is that the callback for these responses is itself going to initiate a process that should be only handled synchronously rather than asynchronously (an update to a stored state).

Comment: Depends on how long it takes for each callback to take place, if you need them to execute in a specific order, I don't think you can use what you have reliably.

Comment: Seems overly complex imo. If you simply want to send off n requests at once, then process them in order once they're all done, all you need is promise.all. If you want to instead send them one at a time, a recursive function will suffice.

Comment: I just want to know if they'll execute in the same order as they are added to the queue.

Comment: promise.all ensures that would be the case.

Comment: I don't think your code works any different from `function genericFetchFunction(url, callback) {
    makeAsyncRequest(url, callback);
}`, as the `responseQueue` would never gain more than one item. What exactly do you need to do sequentially (I assume you don't mean synchronously) when there are multiple calls?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify that I need to update state in response to the callbacks, and the state needs to be updated in a sequential way.
Why would the queue never gain more than one item? if more responses are coming in asynchronously, couldn't they be added to the queue while it's going through its firing process?

Comment: @Marisha No, a response never comes in while something is still processing. JS first finishes the current run before firing the next asynchronous callback.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, that would seem to answer the "why not" of my question. Thank you! Where can I find more information about what a "run" entails?

Comment: Also; it seems I've been punished for asking this question, and that I should avoid doing something similar in the future at risk of losing what little reputation I have. Did I violate any guidelines? What should I do differently?

Comment: You've not been punished.  Perhaps your question has.  Someone did not think the question was up to the SO standards and downvoted. There has been no rush to do so, and the question as it stands looks ok to me.  (If you  haven't read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/), you probably should.)

Comment: Reputation is based on the community-perceived quality of the questions and answers you supply on the site.  Don't worry about it very much now.  But treat up- and down-votes as individual reports on that quality so that you can help learn the ways.  And again, visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn what makes for good questions and answers.

Comment: Take a look at `async` waterfall and parallel techniques. It has all been done before and really simple to reproduce once you work with it, no need for a library to depend one though it’s quite small and stable.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Okay, thank you very much for the feedback. I have a hard time gaining reputation because I can never find a new question to ask (so I was feeling pretty eager since I couldn't find this question anywhere)

Comment: You can gain reputation by *answering* questions as well.  Probably much more quickly, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

For any who come across this question and are suffering from my same misconceptions, it seems this question is derived from a misunderstanding of how asynchronous processing is handled in Javascript. Multiple threads are not true "processing threads" in a hardware sense - rather just queued chunks of code that are iterated over until completion of all chunks. So in my example, nothing new can ever be added to the queue while the queue is still being processed, because that processing is all happening within the same event loop.

I found a good explanation of it in this article: [How Javascript Works](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5) (the 'Dissecting the Event Loop' section) and there is additional information on the Concurrency Model and Event Loop [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Comment: Note that one of the comments in the question pointed you toward `Promise.all` as a way to handle the requirements you seemed to need.  I would concur.  If you want a sequential set of processes to run after a collection of asynchronous ones completes, then it would help to create Promise returns from your asynchronous calls, wrap the returned Promises in an array, then call  `Promise.all` on the array.  You'll get back a new Promise, and when (if?) that's resolved, you will be given an array containing those results in order.  You should be able to build what you want off of that.